# persist value between two pages using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, persistent-storage

i have a one html page in which i am storing few user selected values now and want to use these values on another html page.

i am using jquery in my module and i have already tried window.name and window.localStorage but they don't persist values between two pages.

so please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: More duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+persist

Comment: all above link has the solution that don't work like as far as window.name and window.localStorage they really dont persist data between pages.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally i got pretty cool solution on

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/DOMCached

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want a cookies--and if you're directing from the first page to the second, how about passing the values as GET variables to the next page:

```
http://example.com/newpage.html?var1=blah?var2=blerg
```

then you can access that data with `window.location.search`.

Comment: i can think over it but the restriction is to keep url clean

Comment: That is, frankly, a stupid restriction.

Comment: Using the same principles, it might be "cleaner" to use the hash part of the url instead - this way it has no bearing on the server, and is purely client-side, eg `http://example.com/newpage.html#var1=blah&var2=blerg`
Your javascript in the second page could then read this from `window.location.hash` and then if you wanted to keep the URL clean, you could remove the hash - as it is a hash this would not result in another roundtrip to the server, keeping everything local/client/browser-side

Answer (score 3):

You could use the "hash":

```
http://my.app.com/page2.html#name1=val1&name2=val2
```

The hash would be ignored by the server, keeping things "clean". The second page can read the hash from

```
window.location.hash
```

and then parse out the name/value pairs with some simple string/regexp/array manipulation.

If you wanted the hash to be "hidden", your second page could also then remove the hash from the URL - this would not result in another trip to the server - changes to hash only result in browser/client side behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

If it's just a few values, how about cookies?

Answer (score 0):

Store the value inside a cookie on the first page and and retrive it on the second. Its very easy with the Jquery Cookie plugin http://plugins.jquery.com/project/cookie

Answer (score 0):

You would have to try and use cookies (assuming users are nice enough to enable those).
Here is a very useful link: http://www.w3schools.com/JS/js_cookies.asp